# Client-Server application, how to identify each client

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, server, client

I'm creating client - server application (server in C++ and client in C#) using sockets. Server will accept requests from multiple clients. Each client has individual account created on server. After authentication, I know that client logged in to specific account with ip, the ip is the same for each client because I run all the client from the same computer. The client is able to send a message to another active client and this message has to pass from the server, how can I do to determine the right client to which the server has to dispatch the message?
The following code is the main of the server:

```
void main()
{
    server s1;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = s1.start();

    fd_set master;
    FD_ZERO(&master);

    
    FD_SET(ListenSocket, &master);

    bool running = true; 

    while (running)
    {

        fd_set copy = master;       
        int socketCount = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < socketCount; i++)
        {
            
            SOCKET sock = copy.fd_array[i];         
            if (sock == ListenSocket)
            {                       
                master = s1.acceptation(ListenSocket, master);          
            }
            else // It's an inbound message
            {
                char buf[4096];
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
                            
                int bytesIn = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesIn <= 0)
                {
                    closesocket(sock);
                    FD_CLR(sock, &master);
                }
                else
                {
                    s1.scelta(buf, sock);                                                           
                }
            }
        }
    }

    master = s1.close(ListenSocket,master);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to find a way to identify the clients based on some id on the server side.

Comment: Yes, but which ip address I have to use during the socket creation?

Comment: IP should be the server IP. So what I was thinking is that when clients connect to the server, the server assigns some ID to the client and sends that ID to the client. The client then has to use that ID for sending messages to other clients. You can imagine ID to be a phone number - clients should know each other's ID in order for them to communicate.

Comment: Do you know how Can I insert the ID in my code?

Comment: You need to design a message format (protocol) which you will use for communication between clients and server. Like a struct containing `int id` and `char message[100]`, something like that.

Comment: The problem is how to select the correct socket to send the message to the right client.

Comment: Maintain a mapping of the client ID and the socket descriptor, use this mapping to get the socket descriptor for a given client ID.

Comment: Perfect... Do you have any idea how can I do to make the C# client always ready to receive? I was thinking about using an event

Comment: Run an infinite while loop in a separate thread.